# Add a sequential counter column on groups to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, running-count

I feel like there is a better way than this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns="   index    c1    c2    v1 ".split(),
    data= [
            [       0,  "A",  "X",    3, ],
            [       1,  "A",  "X",    5, ],
            [       2,  "A",  "Y",    7, ],
            [       3,  "A",  "Y",    1, ],
            [       4,  "B",  "X",    3, ],
            [       5,  "B",  "X",    1, ],
            [       6,  "B",  "X",    3, ],
            [       7,  "B",  "Y",    1, ],
            [       8,  "C",  "X",    7, ],
            [       9,  "C",  "Y",    4, ],
            [      10,  "C",  "Y",    1, ],
            [      11,  "C",  "Y",    6, ],]).set_index("index", drop=True)
def callback(x):
    x['seq'] = range(1, x.shape[0] + 1)
    return x
df = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).apply(callback)
print df
```

To achieve this:

```
   c1 c2  v1  seq
0   A  X   3    1
1   A  X   5    2
2   A  Y   7    1
3   A  Y   1    2
4   B  X   3    1
5   B  X   1    2
6   B  X   3    3
7   B  Y   1    1
8   C  X   7    1
9   C  Y   4    1
10  C  Y   1    2
11  C  Y   6    3
```

Is there a way to do it that avoids the callback?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

use `cumcount()`, see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items)

```
In [4]: df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).cumcount()
Out[4]: 
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     1
6     2
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    1
11    2
dtype: int64
```

If you want orderings starting at 1

```
In [5]: df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).cumcount()+1
Out[5]: 
0     1
1     2
2     1
3     2
4     1
5     2
6     3
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    2
11    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful

```
df = df.sort_values(['userID', 'date'])
grp = df.groupby('userID')['ItemID'].aggregate(lambda x: '->'.join(tuple(x))).reset_index()
print(grp)
```

it will create a sequence like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dataframe similar to the one below and you want to add `seq` column by building it from `c1` or `c2`, i.e. keep a running count of similar values (or until a flag comes up) in other column(s), read on.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns="  c1      c2    seq".split(),
    data= [
            [ "A",      1,    1 ],
            [ "A1",     0,    2 ],
            [ "A11",    0,    3 ],
            [ "A111",   0,    4 ],
            [ "B",      1,    1 ],
            [ "B1",     0,    2 ],
            [ "B111",   0,    3 ],
            [ "C",      1,    1 ],
            [ "C11",    0,    2 ] ])
```

then first find group starters, (`str.contains()` (and `eq()`) is used below but any method that creates a boolean Series such as `lt()`, `ne()`, `isna()` etc. can be used) and call `cumsum()` on it to create a Series where each group has a unique identifying value. Then use it as the grouper on a `groupby().cumsum()` operation.

In summary, use a code similar to the one below.

```py
# build a grouper Series for similar values
groups = df['c1'].str.contains("A$|B$|C$").cumsum()

# or build a grouper Series from flags (1s)
groups = df['c2'].eq(1).cumsum()

# groupby using the above grouper
df['seq'] = df.groupby(groups).cumcount().add(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanliness of [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435320/9249533) is nice, but I prefer to sort explicitly...though generally without overwriting my df for these type of use-cases (e.g. [Shaina Raza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61747504/9249533)).

So, to create a new column sequenced by 'v1' within each ('c1', 'c2') group:

```
df["seq"] = df.sort_values(by=['c1','c2','v1']).groupby(['c1','c2']).cumcount()
```

you can check with:

```
df.sort_values(by=['c1','c2','seq'])
```

or, if you want to overwrite the df, then:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['c1','c2','seq']).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the groupby and cumcount functions to achieve your desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['counts'] = df.groupby('col').cumcount() + 1

df
```