# How to create an incremental column that increments based on the same values from another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, increment

I am trying to create an incremental column that increments based on the same id from another column. My dataset consists of 300K rows.
This is the input.

```
id
a
a
b
c
c
c
```

Expected output

```
id    count
a       1
a       2
b       1
c       1
c       2
c       3
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: try pandas groupby cumcount

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add sequential counter column on groups using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435270/how-to-add-sequential-counter-column-on-groups-using-pandas-groupby)

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes, exactly what I was looking for @DishinHGoyani