# How to get the mean value of a columns having condition which specified?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I have a data frame having columns ( Name, a, b) and I want to create a columns name"mean" which would be mean of column a and b, but if mean of any two-row is same then whosever sum value is more should decrease by 0.1.

```
   data frame 1

  Name  Sum  a   b      mean
0 hamm   34  2   2       2
1 jam    54  1   1  -->  1
2 tan    36  3   1       2
3 pan    39  4   4       4
```

as we see now row 0 and 2 have the same mean value, so now whosever sum value is more should decrease by 0.1

Here, in this case, its row no 2 should have value 2- 0.1 = 1.9

**Final Result**

```
  Name  Sum  a   b   mean
0 hamm   34  2   2    2
1 jam    54  1   1    1
2 tan    36  3   1    1.9
3 pan    39  4   4    4
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? I can't think of a reason why it would make any mathematical sense.

Comment: it would definitely make sense ... here "a" and "b" column is a rank for features that I got using different ML models and I want to take a mean of it so I would come to know what features rank overall good . and if the rank ties, then I want to apply this condition which specified, so the one having greater sum should show up. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: What's happen if there are 3 rows with same mean ?

Comment: That's y I want to write generic code so that It could handle situation like this.  @AlexandreB.

Comment: So what is the answer to my question ?

Comment: then the one with the greatest sum will be (mean -0.2 )and the 2nd on will be (mean -0.1 ) and the last one remains unchanged. @AlexandreB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df.assign(mean = df[["a", "b"]].mean(axis=1))\
  .assign(mean = df["mean"].subtract(df.groupby("mean").cumcount().divide(10)))
```

*output*

```
#    Name  Sum  a  b  mean
# 0  hamm   34  2  2   2.0
# 1   jam   54  1  1   1.0
# 2   tan   36  3  1   1.9
# 3   pan   39  4  4   4.0
```

**Explanations**:

1. Compute the mean using [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html). We specify `axis=1` to compute it on rows.
2. For each identical `mean`, we want to substract `n*0.1`.

   1. We use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group all rows with same `mean`
   2. We get their number using [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435270/how-to-add-sequential-counter-column-on-groups-using-pandas-groupby) for more details.
   3. Divide by `10` using [`divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html) in order to convert the counter to `0.1, 0.2, ...`
3. Subtract the output from step 2 to the `mean` column using [`subtract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html)

---

**Full code + illustration**

```
# Step 1
df["mean"] = df[["a", "b"]].mean(axis=1)
print(df)
#    Name  Sum  a  b  mean
# 0  hamm   34  2  2   2.0
# 1   jam   54  1  1   1.0
# 2   tan   36  3  1   2.0
# 3   pan   39  4  4   4.0

# Step 2.1 + 2.2
print(df.groupby("mean").cumcount())
# 0    0
# 1    0
# 2    1
# 3    0
# dtype: int64

# Step 2.3
print(df.groupby("mean").cumcount().divide(10))
# 0    0.0
# 1    0.0
# 2    0.1
# 3    0.0
# dtype: float64

# Step 3
df["mean"] = df["mean"].subtract(df.groupby("mean").cumcount().divide(10))
print(df)
#    Name  Sum  a  b  mean
# 0  hamm   34  2  2   2.0
# 1   jam   54  1  1   1.0
# 2   tan   36  3  1   1.9
# 3   pan   39  4  4   4.0
```

Comment: its doesn't applicable to the problem statement. for ex . in this particular problem it doesn't apply for df.mean ..row 0 & 2.