# Add simple counter column in pandas dataframe which resets when the date changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add a simple counter column in a pandas dataframe which resets when the date changes?  The date is a to_datetime object.  Here is the desired result:

```
Date          Counter
2009-03-20    0
2009-03-20    1
2009-03-20    2
2009-03-20    3
2009-03-20    4
2009-03-20    5
2009-03-25    0
2009-03-25    1
2009-03-25    2
2009-03-25    3
2009-03-26    0
2009-03-26    1
2009-03-26    2
2009-03-26    3
2009-03-26    4
2009-03-26    5
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Date').cumcount()`, can't find the duplicate link, but it is.

Comment: Will your date column always be sorted?

Comment: Ah, I seem to have pasted my response and only now seen this in comments...

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435270/how-to-add-sequential-counter-column-on-groups-using-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 0):

You need to gropuby date & cumcount:

```
>>> df.groupby('Date').cumcount()
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     0
7     1
8     2
9     3
10    0
11    1
12    2
13    3
14    4
15    5
```