# pandas group by and sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a `category` column.

For each class within the `category` column, I would like a repeating sequence from 1 to `n`. For example, in the below table, for each unique value in the `category` column (e.g. `a`, `b`, `c` etc.), I would like to have a repeating sequence from `1 to 3` in the corresponding `sequence` column

| id | category | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 3 | a | 3 |
| 4 | a | 1 |
| 5 | a | 2 |
| 6 | a | 3 |
| 7 | b | 1 |
| 8 | b | 2 |
| 9 | b | 3 |
| 10 | b | 1 |
| 11 | b | 2 |
| 12 | b | 3 |

I would very much appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add sequential counter column on groups using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435270/how-to-add-sequential-counter-column-on-groups-using-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['sequence'] = (df.groupby('category').cumcount() % 3) + 1
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    id category  sequence
0    1        a         1
1    2        a         2
2    3        a         3
3    4        a         1
4    5        a         2
5    6        a         3
6    7        b         1
7    8        b         2
8    9        b         3
9   10        b         1
10  11        b         2
11  12        b         3
```

As an alternative:

```
df['sequence'] = df.groupby('category').cumcount().mod(3).add(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are always a multiple of 3 rows per group, then you don't need to `.groupby`. You can use string multiplication and convert to list / Series:

```
df['sequence'] = list('123'*(df.shape[0]//3))
```

Or if the column datqa type must be `int`, then:

```
df['sequence'] = pd.Series(list('123'*(df.shape[0]//3))).astype(int)
df

Out[1]: 
    id category  sequence
0    1        a         1
1    2        a         2
2    3        a         3
3    4        a         1
4    5        a         2
5    6        a         3
6    7        b         1
7    8        b         2
8    9        b         3
9   10        b         1
10  11        b         2
11  12        b         3
```