# For rows that have repeated column values, how to create another row with a unique count number for that value

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have a dataframe with repeating column values

```
data = {'1':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head(10)
```

```
    1
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   4
7   4
8   4
9   4
```

How would I create another column which has a unique count number for how many times that value has been seen before, going either up or down the rows.

This is an example desired result

```
1   uniquee
0   1   0
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   2   0
4   2   1
5   3   0
6   4   0
7   4   1
8   4   2
9   4   3
```

Going down the rows, for column values of column '1' that has a repeated value, the 'unique' column contains an integer referring to the number of times that value has been seen before.

A solution I came up with is to use iterrows

```
seen_set = {}
df['uniquee'] = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['1'] not in seen_set:
        seen_set[row['1']] = 0
    else:
        seen_set[row['1']] += 1
    df.loc[index , 'uniquee'] =  seen_set[row['1']]
```

But iterrows is generally discouraged as it tends to be slower. Is there a more computationally efficient method?

Comment: Related [How to add sequential counter column on groups using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23435270/15497888)

Comment: @ThePyGuy it's not always sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.assign(unique = df.groupby('1').cumcount())
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the dataframe by the value column, then apply passing a lambda function to create the list of numbers in comprehension, finally explode and reset the index

```py
>>> (df.groupby('1')
    .apply(lambda x: [i for i in range(x.size)])
    .explode().to_frame('unique').reset_index()
     )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   1 unique
0  1      0
1  1      1
2  1      2
3  2      0
4  2      1
5  3      0
6  4      0
7  4      1
8  4      2
9  4      3
```