# How to add sequential counter column on groups using Pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

My question is generated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435270/how-to-add-sequential-counter-column-on-groups-using-pandas-groupby).

Instead of creating a column "seq":

```
    c1 c2  seq
0   A  X   1
1   A  X   2
2   A  Y   1
3   A  Y   2
4   B  X   1
5   B  X   2
6   B  X   3
7   B  Y   1
8   C  X   1
9   C  Y   1
10  C  Y   2
11  C  Y   6
```

I want to create two columns to count X and Y separately, the count should refresh according to c1 column, like below.

```
    c1 c2  Ct_X Ct_Y
0   A  X   1    0
1   A  X   2    0
2   A  Y   2    1
3   A  Y   2    2
4   B  X   1    0
5   B  X   2    0
6   B  X   3    0
7   B  Y   3    1
8   C  X   1    0
9   C  Y   1    1
10  C  Y   1    2
11  C  Y   1    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `groupby` with `transform`:

```
x = df.groupby('c1')['c2']
df['Ct_X'] = x.transform(lambda x: x.eq('X').cumsum())
df['Ct_Y'] = x.transform(lambda x: x.eq('Y').cumsum())
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   c1 c2  seq  Ct_X  Ct_Y
0   A  X    1     1     0
1   A  X    2     2     0
2   A  Y    1     2     1
3   A  Y    2     2     2
4   B  X    1     1     0
5   B  X    2     2     0
6   B  X    3     3     0
7   B  Y    1     3     1
8   C  X    1     1     0
9   C  Y    1     1     1
10  C  Y    2     1     2
11  C  Y    6     1     3
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach but slightly more generic, we can encode `c2` with [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) then take the [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) relative to `c1` then we can [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the newly created columns back to the original DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(
    pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['c2'], prefix='Ct').groupby('c1').cumsum()
)
```

Alternatively [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) can be used instead and pass the grouping Series directly to groupby:

```
df = df.join(
    df['c2'].str.get_dummies().groupby(df['c1']).cumsum().add_prefix('Ct_')
)
```

`df`:

```
   c1 c2  Ct_X  Ct_Y
0   A  X     1     0
1   A  X     2     0
2   A  Y     2     1
3   A  Y     2     2
4   B  X     1     0
5   B  X     2     0
6   B  X     3     0
7   B  Y     3     1
8   C  X     1     0
9   C  Y     1     1
10  C  Y     1     2
11  C  Y     1     3
```

---

How does this work?

`pd.get_dummies` produces "dummy/indicator variables" for all values in `c2`, resulting in:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['c2'], prefix='Ct')

   c1  Ct_X  Ct_Y
0   A     1     0
1   A     1     0
2   A     0     1
3   A     0     1
4   B     1     0
5   B     1     0
6   B     1     0
7   B     0     1
8   C     1     0
9   C     0     1
10  C     0     1
11  C     0     1
```

Now since the indicators are already in 1/0 format we can simply take the cumulative total for each group in `c1` resulting in the desired new columns:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['c2'], prefix='Ct').groupby('c1').cumsum()

    Ct_X  Ct_Y
0      1     0
1      2     0
2      2     1
3      2     2
4      1     0
5      2     0
6      3     0
7      3     1
8      1     0
9      1     1
10     1     2
11     1     3
```

---

**Notes**

1. This approach will calculate the cumulative total for *all* unique values in `c2` per `c1` group.
2. If using `pd.get_dummies` on a DataFrame with more columns than just `c1` and `c2` the DataFrame may need subset like:

```
pd.get_dummies(df[['c1', 'c2']], columns=['c2'], prefix='Ct').groupby('c1').cumsum()
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'c2': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']
})
```