# Pandas groupby on same column twice

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataset like

```py
z = pd.DataFrame({'match': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
                  'group': [0,1,1,2,0,2,1,2],
                  'win':   [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]})
```

Notice, for example, that group "1" and "2" are paired up twice (in match 2 and 4), and in this matchup, group 2 has a 50% win rate.

I want an array that shows the avg win rate of each group pairing, something like

```
    0    1    2
0   -   0.0  0.0
1  1.0   -   0.5
2  1.0  0.5   -
```

but I have no idea how to get there with standard `groupby` and `agg` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option one (Updated):

```
left = z.assign(
  _id = lambda x: x.groupby('match').cumcount()
).pivot('match', '_id',  'group').join(
  z.groupby('match').win.first()
)

# for each match create another row with players reversed and assign 
# the opposite score
right = left.rename(columns={0: 1, 1:0}).assign(win=lambda x: 1-x.win)

left.append(right).groupby([0,1]).win.mean().unstack()

1    0    1    2
0               
0  NaN  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  NaN  0.5
2  1.0  0.5  NaN
```

---

Option two (original answer):

1. Pivot data frame so each row is a match;
2. The win rate of one player over another is basically the average of its scores where both players are not null, i.e. in a match;
3. Use `apply` to calculate all pair wise win rates;

```py
p = z.pivot('match', 'group', 'win')

# calculate the win rate of x over y
def win_rate(x, y):
    if x.name == y.name:
        return None
    return x[x.notnull() & y.notnull()].mean()

# calculate pair wise win rate
p.apply(lambda x: p.apply(lambda y: win_rate(y, x)))

group    0    1    2
group               
0      NaN  0.0  0.0
1      1.0  NaN  0.5
2      1.0  0.5  NaN
```

Comment: @U12-Forward thanks :) Yeah i guess pandas might not be best suited for this type of problem.

Comment: True! Yeap. Almost every answer in pandas is DVed :( Ex: [How to add sequential counter column on groups using Pandas groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69354807)

Comment: @U12-Forward Every once in a while :(

Comment: @jezrael Haha! Great!

Comment: I was hoping there was something simpler but this works like a charm! Thank you