# How to add a date value column in dataframe with repeating names and seasons in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nba-api

NBA dataset per year stats for players with different number of seasons played:
ex:

```
Name         ,  Season,  Points,  Reb
Lebron James,   2003-04, 25ppg,   10red
Lebron James,   2004-05, 26ppg,   10reb
Lebron James,   2005-06, 27ppg,   9reb 
Michael Jordan, 1984-85, 29ppg,   9red
Michael Jordan, 1985-86, 30ppg,   10reb
```

How can I add a column that chronologically labels the years played for a player. So next to 2003-04 would be a 1 for lebron and 2004-05 would be a 2 etc. This would be different because all players have different rookie years and season played.

Comment: [groupby cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) / [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435320/15497888)-> `df['counter'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1`

Comment: Be warned however, with the shown data the column is actually `'Name         '` not `'Name'`. I am unsure if that's a copy error or not. Additionally the sequential counter presupposes the seasons are in chronological order (as they are in the shown sample).