# count function within for loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I would like to create a count function based on a date. So it should start to count from 1 upwards till a new date is found in the dataset and then starts to count from 1 again, see example dataset and expected outcome below for an example:

```
data= pd.DataFrame(
    [[Timestamp('2022-08-05'), 140, 120],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05'), 160, 155],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-06'), 230, 156],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-06'), 230, 155],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-06'), 230, 160],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-06'), 140, 130],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-07'), 140, 131],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-07'), 230, 170]],
    columns=['date', 'power', 'heart rate'])

data_expected =  pd.DataFrame(
    [[Timestamp('2022-08-05'), 140, 120, 1],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-05'), 160, 155, 2],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-06'), 230, 156, 1],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-06'), 230, 155, 2],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-06'), 230, 160, 3],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-06'), 140, 130, 4],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-07'), 140, 131, 1],
    [Timestamp('2022-08-07'), 230, 170, 2]],
    columns=['date', 'power', 'heart rate', 'count'])
```

what would be the best way to approach this, with a for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add sequential counter column on groups using Pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435270/how-to-add-sequential-counter-column-on-groups-using-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your DataFrame, we can use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the column `date` and the method [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the expected result :

```py
data['count'] = data.groupby(['date']).cumcount()+1
```

Output :

```
    date        power   heart rate  count
0   2022-08-05  140     120         1
1   2022-08-05  160     155         2
2   2022-08-06  230     156         1
3   2022-08-06  230     155         2
4   2022-08-06  230     160         3
5   2022-08-06  140     130         4
6   2022-08-07  140     131         1
7   2022-08-07  230     170         2
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
data['count'] = data.groupby['date'].cumcount()
```