# How to create a new pandas dataset column which increments its value based on the value in a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With the pandas dataframe below (which is a set of results, per team, ordered chronologically)

| Team | Result |
| --- | --- |
| TeamA | Win |
| TeamA | Loss |
| TeamA | Win |
| TeamB | Loss |
| TeamB | Loss |
| TeamC | Loss |
| TeamC | Win |
| TeamC | Win |
| TeamC | Loss |
| TeamC | Loss |

I want to iterate through the dataset and add a new column ("GameNumber") which denotes whether a game is the 1st, 2nd etc. game of each team's season.

i.e. the GameNumber value continues to increment until it find a row where the "Team" value differs from the row above. When it finds such a row, it resets the counter and begins counting from '1' again.

- **Sample desired result**

| Team | Result | GameNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TeamA | Win | 1 |
| TeamA | Loss | 2 |
| TeamA | Win | 3 |
| TeamB | Loss | 1 |
| TeamB | Loss | 2 |
| TeamC | Loss | 1 |
| TeamC | Win | 2 |
| TeamC | Win | 3 |
| TeamC | Loss | 4 |
| TeamC | Loss | 5 |

Many thanks!

I've tried various pandas functions (incl. explode & groupby) but these don't seem to meet the need.

Comment: Did you change your output in the edit? there were only values for the Loss rows

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and a mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['GameNumber'] = (df.groupby('Team').cumcount().add(1)
                      .where(df['Result'].eq('Loss'), '')
                    )
```

Output:

```
    Team Result GameNumber
0  TeamA    Win           
1  TeamA   Loss          2
2  TeamA    Win           
3  TeamB   Loss          1
4  TeamB   Loss          2
5  TeamC   Loss          1
6  TeamC    Win           
7  TeamC    Win           
8  TeamC   Loss          4
9  TeamC   Loss          5
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing mozway. However, as you can see, the output produced by your code suggestion does not match the "Sample desired result" table above.

However this code:

df2["GameNumber"] = df2.groupby(['Team']).cumcount()+1

from the item below meets the need exactly

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435270/add-a-sequential-counter-column-on-groups-to-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @Philby_Walsh this is because your [original question's formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/84e143e2-671f-4d96-a0d7-1f393bc852c2/view-source) displayed the data in a way that suggested that you only wanted values when the Result was Loss, which you then fixed after I answered ;)

Comment: That explains it, many thanks Mozway!